# Ejb Finder(ejb-ql) Transaction TimesOut

Tags: java, oracle10g, ejb, weblogic9.x, ejbql

We have been facing an issue, where a simple ejb-ql query runs out of transaction time, if same(WL generated SQL version of ejb-ql) is run from SQL command prompt, it takes very less time than the configured JTA time(execute less than 5% time of JTA).

Erros: Few time the error thrown is:

> javax.ejb.FinderException: Exception in 'finderMethodName' while using result set: 'weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl@9c18f'
>   java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: Transaction rolled back: **Transaction timed out after 301 seconds**

Note - JTA is configured to 300 seconds

Most of the time the error thrown is:

> javax.ejb.FinderException: Exception in 'finderMethodName' while using result set: 'weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl@a5af'
>   java.sql.SQLException: **Result set already closed**

Comment: have you checked in your db if you get any deadlocks? Are you using any kind of locking?

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the timeout in the container.

Service Configurations -> Other Services

Click JTA Configuration(Under Other Services)

Then you will see the Timeout Seconds on the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Increasing the timeout setting might not help, as I mentioned the SQL equivalent of the EJB-QL for the finder returns within few seconds. I am not able to guess where the time is going, a) is the time going to execute the query or b) is app server waiting for some resource(like to get the connection) or c) the cmp finder returned the result, however the iteration over resultset is taking time.